# time delay not helping

Tags: python, json, api

Im working with Python 3 and the Americommerce API. I found an issue where when I initially grab the json for a order that has just been placed, it shows the payment is still waiting to go through the system. So the json shows the following values: is_declined=false, is_accepted=false. When I check the json after the order has gone through this has has changed. I need to get the json after its been changed. There seems to be some kind of delay on their end, I think its to allow for the payment to be ran through their system.

In my server file I added a time delay before parsing the json hoping that would get the updated json. This doesn't change anything. Ive tried up to 90 seconds but when it runs it doesnt seem to have any delay at all so I still get the initial json:
this is the code in my server file. Once the webhook is triggered
the data variable parses the json, my delay does't help

```
time.sleep(90)
data = json.loads(self.rfile.read( length ).decode('utf-8'))
```

update:
code that makes the request:

```
class Webhook: # pylint: disable=R0903
    """
    reusable webhook class
    """

    def subscribe(self, event_type, methods=None):
        """Import data from the webhook subscription."""
        import json
        import locale
        from requests import post
        from classes import helper
        erase_chars = helper.Helper()

        if methods is None:
            methods = []
            methods.append(1)

        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

        with open('config.json') as api_config:
            api = json.load(api_config)

        store_domain = api['wh_test']['store_domain']
        access_token = api['wh_test']['token']

        headers = {
            'X-AC-Auth-Token': access_token,
            'Content-Type'   : 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control'  : 'no-cache'
        }

        # destination url is set in config.json
        server_url  = 'http://{}:{}'.format(api['python_server']['host'],api['python_server']['port'])
        payload = {
            'event_type'  : event_type,
            'url'         : server_url,
            'failure_type': 'Fallback',
            'store_id'    : 1,
            'cache_length': 'Short',
            'fallback_url': server_url,
        }
        print('failure: ', erase_chars.strip(event_type))
        uri = 'https://{}/api/v1/webhooks'.format(store_domain)

        return_data = post(uri, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: Can you add your code that makes the actual request?

Comment: sure! I just added the code

Comment: Please format the code properly, it looks like the `class` definition line didn't get formatted. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can solve this problem with some kind of arbitrary timeout - how can you know the the amount of time you choose will work on slower networks, for example? If your post returns data, it should either successfully return data or provide an error code (400, 404, etc).